# Как переставить окно Database

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы вкладка `Database` была всплывающей и располагалась справа как `Ant Build` и `Maven Projects`. Никак не пойму как это сделать...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете включить "Плавающий режим" - "Floating Mode" в настройках вкладки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а после этого изменить размер и/или перетащить вкладку куда желаете:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К тому же, если вы включите "Pinned Mode", вкладка будет раскрыта всегда, независимо от того, где будет находиться ваш курсор. В случае, если вы выключите "Pinned Mode", вкладка в неактивном состоянии будет автоматически скрыта.